# C linked list to Display contents

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

Is there any part i have missed in the code?

I am creating a non-empty linked
list and to display the contents of a linked list. Where am I getting it wrong?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_int
{
    void *data;
    node next;
};

typedef struct node_int *node;
typedef struct list_int { node first; } *list;

void init_list(list *lp, void *o)
{
    *lp = (list) malloc(sizeof(struct list_int));
    (*lp)->first = NULL;
    (*lp)->first->data = o;
    (*lp)->first->next = NULL;
}

void print(list ell, void (*print_data)(void *d))
{
    list c;
    c = ell;
    while (c!NULL)
    {
        print_data(c->data);
        c = ell;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(*lp)->first = NULL; (*lp)->first->data = o;` : `NULL->data = o;` !!

Comment: `print_data(c->data); c = ell;` not update `c`.

Comment: Can you please post compilable code, or give a better indication of the overall program and where it is breaking, so that we know where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First like to say that I find it bad style to `typedef` a pointer. If you do that, you should at least use a name which clearly tells that the type is a pointer. Names like `list` and `node` make others think of something which is **not** pointers.

Below is some code showing how it could look without typedef'ed pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_int
{
    void *data;
    struct node_int* next;
};

typedef struct node_int node;
typedef struct list_int { node* first; } list;


void init_list(list** lp, void *o)
{
    // Allocate the list
    *lp = malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (*lp == NULL) return;

    // Allocate the first node
    (*lp)->first = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if ((*lp)->first == NULL)
    {
        free(*lp);
        *lp = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // Initialize first element
    (*lp)->first->data = o;
    (*lp)->first->next = NULL;
}

void print(list* ell, void (*print_data)(void *d))
{
    if (ell == NULL) return;

    node* p = ell->first;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        print_data(p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void myPrint(void* d)
{
  int* p = (int*)d;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
}

void free_list(list* ell)
{
    // Add code here ...
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    list* myList;
    init_list(&myList, &a);
    if (myList == NULL) return 0;

    // Use the list.....
    print(myList, myPrint);

    free_list(myList);
    return 0;
}
```